# Web-part snippet to page layout

Tags: web-part, page-layout, snippet

I would like to add a **web part snippet** to a page layout. Unfortunately I see instruction about adding a web part zone (snippet), but not a specific web part going to all pages.
MS suggests "add Web Parts directly to a master page or page layout. This means content authors cannot...", but I was unable to find out how.
I tried to add it directly in SPD to my layout, but on one side it does nto allow me to chioce whch web part I want, on the other it wants to chenge the html page to asp - and of course it won't work.
It seems it should be simple, but I couldn't solve so far.

Does anybody know how to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK I have found it. You have to choose "**Other Web Parts**" snippet. In my case (Visio Web-Part) the row is the very last one.